# No possessive pronoun in '[first name] and family' OK in US English?

Tags: american-english

Is the following OK in US English:

"Fred lent Tony money for the downpayment on an apartment so that Tony and family could have their own place to live."

Or would I need to add 'his' before 'family', as in UK English?

Thanks

Comment: It does occur, but it's not common, and personally I think it's often a somewhat facetious usage (riffing off the headlinese / business name styling of ***Smith and Company, Jones and Sons***, etc.). It's also reminiscent of Victorian public schoolboy slang, typified by [Stalky & Co.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalky_%26_Co.) - a novel by Rudyard Kipling about adolescent boys at a British boarding school. I'd advise against the usage in more general contexts.

Comment: It would probably not be considered "formal", but it is reasonably well accepted.

Comment: On the Quirk-Svartvik scale of OKness?

Answer (score 1):

The expression "Tony and family" suggests some sort of formal title, as for a business or performing group (*c.f.* "Sanford And Son") or perhaps a reservation at a restaurant.

If done in a jocular tone, it's fine, but if you are being purely neutral, it's "Tony and his family".